# Need help saving the state of player controls in Video Player

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am working on a application with a video player, the frontend is developed in HTML5 with Knockoutjs !!

Now, I am trying to save the state of the play/pause button. Here my requirement is ..

-When I pause the video and try to seek it ahead, and when I leave the seekbar it should maintain it's paused state

- And when it is in playing state and when I seek it ahead, it should be play state after seeking forward.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the HTML for player controls...

```
<!-- playback controls -->
        <div class="clearfix playback-set1">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="edit-btn-list-container">
                    <ul class="unstyled-list edit-btn-list clearfix">
                        <li style="margin-top: 8px; width: 45px; margin-left: 0;">
                            <a data-bind="click:play, event:{ended:playerOnEnded}" class="btn btn-alt btn-default" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Play" style="font-size: 25px;"><span data-bind="if: !playerPlaying()"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span><span data-bind="if: playerPlaying"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a data-bind="click:rewindClick" class="btn btn-alt btn-default" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Rewind"><i class="fa fa-fast-backward fa-fw"></i><!-- ko if:intervalRewind() != null --><span data-bind="text:playbackRateIndicator"></span><!-- /ko --></a></li>
                        <li><a data-bind="event:{mousedown:function(){startstep('backward');}}" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-alt btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Step Backward"><i class="fa fa-step-backward fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a data-bind="event:{mousedown:function(){startstep('forward');}}" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-alt btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Step Forward"><i class="fa fa fa-step-forward fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a data-bind="click:fastForwardClick" class="btn btn-alt btn-default" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Fast Forward"><!-- ko if:intervalRewind() == null --><span data-bind="text:playbackRateIndicator"></span><!-- /ko --><i class="fa fa-fast-forward fa-fw"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Here's the Javascript code for seekbar

```
 self.slideScrubber = function (event, ui) {
    self.pauseVideo();
    var secsScrubbedTo = TimecodeMath.Timecode.getFileRelativeSeconds(ui.currentTarget.value, self.frameRate());

          // if scrub to point is currently outside of constrained clip playback points, break out of it:
        if (self.playClipConstrained() && (self.playClipConstrained().startTime > secsScrubbedTo || self.playClipConstrained().endTime < secsScrubbedTo)) {
            self.playClipConstrained(null);
        }
        self.seekTo(secsScrubbedTo);
  }
```

Comment: and what is the trouble you are having ?

Comment: Whenever I pause and seek it ahead it stays paused and when I play and seek it forward it does not maintain the state it goes back to pause state instead of play state

Comment: Nice..any video library that your using ?

Comment: Uhmm I don't really know, but the data is coming through my firm's api... I am new hire.. working on this part right now.